# Android Compose Box clip - place children relative to clip

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, clip

I have a box as a parent with some custom clip.
I need the children to have width and height relative to Box clip not Box sizes.

```
Box(
 modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().clip(WideRectangleShape)
) {
   Image(1)
   Image(2)
   Image(3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get bounds of a `Shape` as `Rect` by turning it into a `Outline`. I'm posting an example how you can do it. You don't have to do it inside `Modifier.layout` but you need to get Size that shape is drawn with

```
val shape = RectangleShape

val density = LocalDensity.current
val layoutDirection = LayoutDirection.Ltr


Box(
    modifier = Modifier.layout { measurable, constraints ->
        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)

        val width = placeable.width
        val height = placeable.height

        val outline = shape.createOutline(
            Size(
                width.toFloat(),
                height.toFloat()
            ),
            layoutDirection,
            density
        )

        val rectangle: Rect = outline.bounds

        layout(width, height) {
            placeable.placeRelative(x = rectangle.right.toInt(), y = rectangle.top.toInt())
        }
    }
) {
        // Images here
}
```